# Groupby (?) dataframe by specfic list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to create a table that groups on a specific subset of Titles, given as a list (group1) and shows the count for each Title. My desired output looks something like that:

group1: full, 2 
group1: part, 1 
B1: full, 1 
C13: full 1

The groupby that's in the current version of the code works ~fine but I'm not sure how to incorporate the 'group1' list.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'C13'], 
                    'Whole': ['full', 'full', 'part','full','full']})

df_count = df.groupby(['Title', 'Whole']).agg({'Whole' : ['count']})

group1 = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']

print(df)
print(df_count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'C13'], 
                    'Whole': ['full', 'full', 'part','full','full']})

group1 = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']

from collections import Counter

m = ~df['Title'].isin(group1)
print( df.groupby(m.cumsum() * m).agg({'Title': set, 'Whole': Counter}) )
```

Prints:

```
              Title                   Whole
Title                                      
0      {A2, A1, A3}  {'full': 2, 'part': 1}
1              {B1}             {'full': 1}
2             {C13}             {'full': 1}
```

Comment: That' exactly what I was looking for. It's a little above my skill level so I will go ahead and understand it. Thank you.

Comment: How would I go about it if I just want a "group1" or if I want to specify multiple groups?

Comment: @Olka That's a little bit more complicated. I suggest to open a new question here on Stack Overflow and describe your problem (along with code you've already tried).